# Extending ActiveRecord::Base not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to extend ActiveRecord::Base with some auditing functionality. When a user saves a model I update two columns - created_by_user_id and/or updated_by_user_id - with their user id. The user_id comes from RequestRegistry.

I just can't get it to work. See code below.

```
module AuditTrail
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :update_audit_fields
  end

  private

  def update_audit_fields
    puts "Updating audit fields" # note this is not being printed out!
    fields_to_update.each do |column|
      column = column.to_s
      # if has_attribute?(column)
      # self[column] = RequestRegistry.current_user.id
      puts "Updating #{column} with user_id some user id"
      # end
    end
  end

  def fields_to_update
    if self.new_record?
      audit_fields
    else
      update_audit_fields
    end
  end

  def audit_fields
    create_audit_fields + update_audit_fields
  end

  def update_audit_fields
    [:updated_by_user_id]
  end

  def create_audit_fields
    [:created_by_user_id]
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, AuditTrail)


class RequestRegistry
  extend ActiveSupport::PerThreadRegistry

  attr_accessor :current_user
end
```

When I simplify it to the code below. The puts statement prints out where as in the first piece of code nothing gets printing out. Also the console is not showing any breaks or errors in the code.

```
module AuditTrail
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :update_audit_fields
  end

  private

  def update_audit_fields
    puts "Updating audit fields"
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, AuditTrail)
```

I have tried to extend the simpler version slowly, but it randomly stops working.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but have you looked at the `paper_trail` gem?  It's very easy to use and it's nice to not have to re-invent the wheel. :)

Comment: Thanks @ihaztehcodez I forgot about paper_trail, but I think that is a little overkill for what I am trying to do. For now I just want basic created_by and updated_by. If I need to extend some tables to include history I will definitely look at this. "Mental note" :)

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You are intentionally breaking the Controller/Model separation by injecting a request context into the model. There is a reason why this is intentionally hard, because it should not happen. If you want a model to have the visibility over the current user, you should create a method in the model that accepts that user as argument.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I think in this case it is fine to break the rules. Practically it is quite a lot of extra code for hardly any gain. If you can suggest a way of sending through the current user with each update/create that is sent from a controller I would love to hear it.

Comment: I already explained how to do that. Do not use Rails built-in save/update methods directly in the controller (which is in any case a bad habit) but use custom methods. Define a `Model.user_create(user, attributes = {})` that sets the user, and triggers the model save. In that way you are doing dependency injection of the user. Another reason why doing what you are doing is bad, is because it assumes there is always a request user (which in fact is false if you create an object from a mail, a CLI, a background job, etc etc). That's why the user should be explicitly passed.

Comment: The other option I thought was to create a generic model that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base and then all my models inherit from that, but that also felt like a lot of admin that could create bugs if people forgot to inherit correctly when generating models. Alternative suggestions welcome, but it would be great to know why this piece of code isn't working.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I am not following your comment. I want to be able to store created_by_user_id on any model. So if a blog post is updated for example the updated_by_user_id would already be set. In terms of it not always being a user doing the update, my code will be corrected to handle that. Right now I am just trying to get this scenario to work. Further I don't think it helps to pollute all your controllers with repetitive code when you could contain it to a single place across all tables/models. Thanks for the suggestions - would appreciate if you expanded on your comment.

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes There are tons of articles that explain what is an MVC pattern, and why what you want to do breaks this pattern and it's a very bad idea. And there is a reason why it's not even contemplated in Rails. This alone should make you think about it. Feel free to proceed your way, after all you are going to maintain it.

Comment: I might be following now. Do you want me to create a method on all my models e.g. MyModel.create_my_model(user, attributes={}) and this would need to be done for update? Then updated all my controllers to accept a user? The amount of work involved in doing this when I could simply handle it in one place feels much more convincing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69208/discussion-between-ryan-neal-mes-and-simone-carletti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You duplicate definition of method update_audit_fields.
In this case second definition overwrite your method with puts.

Comment: Epic! I have been staring at that code for a while and it's been right there. Just needed a fresh pair of eyes. Shot.